# Simulating byte overflow in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, byte, overflow, encode

I would like to simulate byte overflow in VB.NET.
The code below achieves the correct result but I suspect this is not the most efficient method. Is there a simpler/better way to achieve this?

```
 Dim src As Byte = 232
 Dim key As Byte = 231
 Dim encoded As Byte = 0
 Dim decoded As Byte = 0

 ' Encode
 encoded = CByte((CInt(src) + CInt(key)) Mod 256I)

 ' Decode
 Dim tmp As Int32 = CInt(encoded) - CInt(key)
 decoded = CByte(IIf(tmp < 0, 256I + tmp, tmp))

 ' encoded = 207
 ' decoded = src = correct
```

Comment: if you want feedback on your working code, a better place to ask is codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make that a lot faster.  It however requires a project building option change.  Add a new project to your solution.  Right-click it, Properties, Build tab, scroll down, click the Advanced Compile Options button.  Tick the "Remove integer overflow checks" option.

Now you can write it like this:

```
    Dim src As Byte = 232
    Dim key As Byte = 231
    Dim encoded As Byte = src + key
    Dim decoded As Byte = encoded - key
```

Which you'd do in Public methods you expose from your new project.

Do beware the very questionable utility of a Caesar cipher, it is far too easy to crack.  The System.Cryptography namespace has much better alternatives, doesn't require you to tinker with global build options that have tricky side-effects either.